# pom config inheritance - maven surefire plugin

Tags: java, junit, pom.xml, maven-surefire-plugin, parent-pom

I have a java project the has 3 "levels" in it.
The pom in my top maven directory is looks like this:

```
<groupId>com.my_app</groupId>
<artifactId>my_app</artifactId>
<version>LATEST-SNAPSHOT</version>

<modules>
    <module>first_module</module>
    <module>second_module</module>
</modules>
...
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.22.1</version>
        <configuration>
            <parallel>classes</parallel>
            <threadCount>10</threadCount>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

**first_module** (second level) pom is:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.my_app</groupId>
    <artifactId>my_app</artifactId>
    <version>LATEST-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<groupId>com.my_app.first_module</groupId>
<artifactId>first_module</artifactId>
<version>LATEST-SNAPSHOT</version>
...
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <version>2.22.1</version>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

and finally, (**3rd level**) the pom the of the project that actually has test classes in it:

```
<parent>
    <artifactId>first_module</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.my_app.first_module</groupId>
    <version>LATEST-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<artifactId>my_project</artifactId>
...
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.22.1</version>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

My question is - does this structure of poms allow for configuration inheritance from the top to the bottom pom? I mean, if I have the **parallel** configuration in the first pom in the **maven-sirefure-plugin** - will it take affect in test classes under **first_module** and under **my_project** ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`pluginManagement`](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Plugin_Management) tag in the parent's pom. Basically, `<pluginManagement/>` defines the settings for plugins that will be inherited by modules in your build:

```
<pluginManagement>
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.22.1</version>
        <configuration>
            <parallel>classes</parallel>
            <threadCount>10</threadCount>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
</pluginManagement>
```

Then, in the children's pom:

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

You don't need to specify the version, since it's inherited from the parent with all the configuration.

Comment: thanks a lot! and if I want to have project specific config, I can just add it in the child pom? and it will include both config from the parent and the child?

Comment: @OfekAgmon Yes, you can override the configuration within child's plugin.

Comment: But for example - lets say I have in the parent pom the parallel config (<parallel>classes</parallel>), can I add in the child pom another different config and will they both work? or once I have the configuration tag in the child pom - it overrides the entire config of the parent?

Comment: It will apply first the parent then the child config, so it won't override  the entire config of the parent.